# How to format powerpoint text box in visual basic

Tags: vba, visual-studio-2010, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

I'm using Visual Basic in PowerPoint 2010 and I'm writing a script to import a set of pictures to a slide and create **text boxes**

I'm having trouble formatting the text boxes correctly. How can I:

- set opaque white fill
- set bold black text
- set 2 pt black border

Below is my sample subprocess:

```
    Sub import_pics()


    ' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- '
    ' --------------------------------- set the slide layout parameters --------------------------------- '
    ' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- '

    slide_width_in = 10
    slide_height_in = 6.25

    slide_width_pt = slide_width_in * 72
    slide_height_pt = slide_height_in * 72

    banner_height_pct = 0.17
    banner_height_pt = (slide_height_pt * banner_height_pct)

    footer_height_pct = 0.05
    footer_height_pt = (slide_height_pt * footer_height_pct)

    side_margin_pct = 0.02
    side_margin_pt = (slide_width_pt * side_margin_pct)

    top_bottom_margin_pct = 0.02
    top_bottom_margin_pt = ((slide_height_pt - banner_height_pt - footer_height_pt) * top_bottom_margin_pct)

    num_pic_columns_on_slide = 2
    pic_default_width_pt = ((slide_width_pt - 2 * side_margin_pt) / num_pic_columns_on_slide) - (2 * side_margin_pt)

    pic_default_aspect_ratio = 718 / 1000
    pic_default_height_pt = pic_default_width_pt * pic_default_aspect_ratio

    intended_pic_rows = 2
    maximum_allowed_height_of_pic = ((slide_height_pt - banner_height_pt - footer_height_pt) / intended_pic_rows) - (2 * top_bottom_margin_pt)

    If pic_default_height_pt > maximum_allowed_height_of_pic Then
        pic_default_height_pt = maximum_allowed_height_of_pic
        pic_default_width_pt = maximum_allowed_height_of_pic * (1 / pic_default_aspect_ratio)
    End If

    pic_1_top = banner_height_pt + 1 * top_bottom_margin_pt
    pic_2_top = banner_height_pt + 1 * top_bottom_margin_pt
    pic_3_top = banner_height_pt + 3 * top_bottom_margin_pt + (1 * pic_default_height_pt)
    pic_4_top = banner_height_pt + 3 * top_bottom_margin_pt + (1 * pic_default_height_pt)

    pic_1_left = 1 * side_margin_pt
    pic_2_left = 3 * side_margin_pt + (1 * pic_default_width_pt)
    pic_3_left = 1 * side_margin_pt
    pic_4_left = 3 * side_margin_pt + (1 * pic_default_width_pt)

    Dim slideObject As Slide
    Dim longSlideCount As Long

    ' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- '
    ' --------------------------------- construct the slide --------------------------------------------- '
    ' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- '

    longSlideCount = ActivePresentation.Slides.Count

    With ActivePresentation.Slides
        Set slideObject = .Add(longSlideCount + 1, ppLayoutTitleOnly)
    End With

    slideObject.Shapes.Title.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Slide 1"

    Set tbox1 = slideObject.Shapes.AddTextbox( _
                Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
                Left:=100, _
                Top:=250, _
                Width:=72, _
                Height:=50).TextFrame.TextRange



    tbox1.Text = "hello"
    tbox1.Font.Bold = msoTrue
    tbox1.Font.Name = "Calibri"
    tbox1.Font.Size = 10
    tbox1.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter

    ' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- '

    ' how can I set the text box to have:
    '  --> opaque white fill
    '  --> bold black text
    '  --> 2 pt black border

    ' --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- '

    Set pic1 = slideObject.Shapes.AddPicture( _
   FileName:="sample_pic1.png", _
   LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
   SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=pic_1_left, Top:=pic_1_top)

   pic1.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
   pic1.Width = pic_default_width_pt

    Set pic2 = slideObject.Shapes.AddPicture( _
   FileName:="sample_pic2.png", _
   LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
   SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=pic_2_left, Top:=pic_2_top)

   pic2.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
   pic2.Width = pic_default_width_pt

    Set pic3 = slideObject.Shapes.AddPicture( _
   FileName:="sample_pic3.png", _
   LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
   SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=pic_3_left, Top:=pic_3_top)

   pic3.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
   pic3.Width = pic_default_width_pt

    Set pic4 = slideObject.Shapes.AddPicture( _
   FileName:="sample_pic4.png", _
   LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
   SaveWithDocument:=msoTrue, Left:=pic_4_left, Top:=pic_4_top)

   pic4.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
   pic4.Width = pic_default_width_pt

End Sub
```

Thanks! =D

Comment: Sub → Sub Routine (not sub process)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of setting a reference to the textbox's .TextFrame.TextRange, set it to the new shape itself, then

```
With tbox1.TextFrame.TextRange
  .Text = "hello"
  .Font.Bold = True
End With
With tbox1.Fill
  .Visible = True
  .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255,255,255)
end with
With tbox1.Line
  .Visible = True
  .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0,0,0)
  .Weight = 2
End With
```

Comment: thanks Steve! this worked well for me. for bonus points do you know the attribute responsible for bringing the text box to the front of the slide? or perhaps where to find the appropriate documentation for this? thanks =D

Comment: tbox1.ZOrder(msoBringToFront)  (and intellisense will show you the other ZOrder options)